# Calling a class function in an IF statment, keeps returning True

Tags: python, function, class, if-statement, module

I have a class Player() with a function called use_potion(). When I am using use_potion() in an IF statement, at first it works fine. When the return value for use_potion changes, the if statement ignores the change!

Here's a section of the code:

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        inventory = ["potion"]

    def has_potion(self):
        return any(item == "Potion" for item in self.inventory):
```

In another module:

```
from Player import Player

def available_actions():
    moves = ["go east","go west"]
    if Player().has_potion():
        moves.append("use potion")
    return moves
```

When I call available_actions(), it returns all three moves as it is supposed to. But when "potion" is removed from the Player().inventory, available_actions STILL returns all three moves instead of only "go east" and "go west".
I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: `available_actions` creates a fresh `Player` instance each time you call it. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: `Player.__init__` isn't making an `inventory` instance attribute; that's a local variable there, and it's just going to be discarded.

Comment: Also, after you fix those problems, the `inventory` defined in `__init__()` contains a `potion`, but `has_potion()` tests for `Potion`, which is not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating a new `Player` every time you call `available_actions`.  Because the `Player` class comes with a potion, it will always return `True`.

Also, you need to save `inventory` to `self` in your init function.

You should instantiate the player outside of the function and then pass it as a parameter.

```
from Player import Player

my_player = Player()

def available_actions(player):
    moves = ["go east","go west"]
    if player.has_potion():
        moves.append("use potion")
    return moves

available_actions(my_player)
```

and in the Player.py file

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inventory = ["potion"]

    def has_potion(self):
        return 'potion' in self.inventory
```

Comment: Note also, you can make your code for has_potion simpler using just return "potion" in self.inventory. This will evaluate to true, if there is an item "potion" in that list.

Comment: I used the Player() class as an argument and it worked perfectly! The change to the has_potion function worked as well so thank you. But to make sure I understand why this worked, by adding an argument to the available_actions function, it took in the Player() class instead of an instance of that class?